# A question about the number of degenerate cubic curves of a pencil

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have read a post about counting degenerate cubic curves in the pencil of two non-degenerate cubic curves.
[Count degenerate cubic curves in the pencil of two non-degenerate cubic curves](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4656673/count-degenerate-cubic-curves-in-the-pencil-of-two-non-degenerate-cubic-curves) There is an answer saying that the only cubic curves with singularity is the nodal cubic. But I don't know why.

Meanwhile, I want to point out that if there is a reducible cubic crossing the nine points, for example, a line and a conic, then it will have euler charateristic of 2. So even we acknowledge that there are only nodal cubics how can we get the answer that the number of it is 12?

Comment: I left out the word "irreducible" when describing the general singular fibers; the reducible cubic does not occur. This is a much more delicate count when you aren't looking at a general pencil.

Comment: I get it. You presuppose the reducible cubic does not occur, right?

Comment: While there is still a question I mentioned above, why there can only  be nodal cubics as the singularity curves?

Comment: The key phrase to look up is "Lefschetz pencil."

Comment: OK, I think I get it.